# adding files to ~/.local/bin doesn't add it to the $PATH

Tags: paths, execute-command

I've added fm6000 file to the ~/.local/bin folder assuming it'll be the same as adding it to /usr/bin folder. Though that's not the case. There are many files in ~/.local/bin folder that don't work. I've checked the perms and it is executable.

Ubuntu: 22.04 (LTS)

Comment: `~/.local/bin` is not added to the `PATH` by default AFAIK (`~/bin` is, by the default `~/.profile`).

Comment: You can *append* it to your $PATH in ~/.bashrc: `export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin"` putting your own username in where I have 'user'. And / or put the same in `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check

- If the directory was not there, you can create it. It will *only* be added to the path once you log out then back in, so `.profile` is read. So make sure you have logged out then back in.
- Ubuntu automatically adds a directory `~/.local/bin` to the path if it exists. This is set up in your default `~/.profile` configuration file.

  - If you changed your `~./profile` configuration file, then check and repair it. An easy way to revert to a default file is to copy it back from `/etc/skel/`.
  - If not, then check what else may be changing the PATH, e.g. statements in your `~/.bashrc` configuration file.